# Returning row number using sapply

Tags: r

I am trying to start moving away from loops in R, but am having trouble figuring out how to return information on the progress of the sapply function. For example, if I want to process a vector and print out what row I am processing, using a loop I write:

```
vec = c(1:10)
out = NULL
for (i in 1:length(vec)){
    print(paste("Processing item ",i,sep=""))
    y = vec[i]^2
    out = c(out,y)
}
```

How can I do the same thing with sapply? Here is the code I have.

```
func = function(x) {
    #print (paste("Processing item ",x,sep="")) ## This is where I want to print out the row number being processed.
    x^2
}

out = sapply(vec,func)
```

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Maybe use `sprintf` like this: `sprintf('Processing item %s, value: %s', 1:length(vec), vec^2)`?

Comment: `sprintf` can do what I want to do. I modified the code to output the results to a vector and the output to the screen. `sprintf('Processing item %s, value: %s', 1:length(vec), out=sapply(vec,func))`. Not sure if this is klugey or not, but it works for me. Thanks. If you add your comment to answers, I will select it.

Comment: Done. If `funx` only does `x^2`, then the sapply call inside `sprintf` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with just the `sprintf`-function:

```
sprintf('Processing item %s, value: %s', 1:length(vec), vec^2)
```

which gives:

```
 [1] "Processing item 1, value: 1"   
 [2] "Processing item 2, value: 4"   
 [3] "Processing item 3, value: 9"   
 [4] "Processing item 4, value: 16"  
 [5] "Processing item 5, value: 25"  
 [6] "Processing item 6, value: 36"  
 [7] "Processing item 7, value: 49"  
 [8] "Processing item 8, value: 64"  
 [9] "Processing item 9, value: 81"  
[10] "Processing item 10, value: 100"
```

---

Another option would be to define your function a bit differently:

```
func <- function(x) {
  p <- paste0("Processing item ", 1:length(x))
  y <- x^2
  cbind.data.frame(p, y)
}
```

When you now use `func(vec)` it returns a dataframe:

```
                    p   y
1   Processing item 1   1
2   Processing item 2   4
3   Processing item 3   9
4   Processing item 4  16
5   Processing item 5  25
6   Processing item 6  36
7   Processing item 7  49
8   Processing item 8  64
9   Processing item 9  81
10 Processing item 10 100
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the [`pbapply`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pbapply) package for "Adding Progress Bar to '*apply' Functions"

After installing the package, run `example("pbsapply")` to view the provided examples for this function.

Comment: This seems like a lot of overhead code to be adding, in my opinion. I really just want a way to print the row number.

Answer (score 2):

You could process the indices instead and access the values in the function:

```
vec = LETTERS[1:10]
func = function(x) {
  paste("Processing item ", x, ", val:" , vec[x], sep="")
}

sapply(1:length(vec),func)
```

Comment: your proposed solution sends the printed output to both the console and the output file. I don't actually want it included in the output file, just the console. Is there a way to not include in output

Comment: of course, just remove the `print()`, see the edit above.

Comment: The code still print to the output. For example, out = sapply(1:length(vec),func) prints the output to out.

Comment: then why would use assign it to a variable if you dont want to assign it to the variable?

Comment: I want to send the progress update to the console, but return the values to a variable, as in the example I provided. In the for loop, the progress is printed to the console, while the values that I am interested in are saved to a variable.